# Liferay Portlet do not appear in the menu option for portlet

Tags: liferay

I am following the official Liferay tutorial 7.1,

I have started the server and installed the first "guestbook portlet".
However, it is not showing in the list of available portlets (the menu which shows when you click on the + button ).

I went back to Eclipse and I can see that my module ( the only one I have ) has an error symbol on it. However, no error message is displayed anywhere.

[image]

This is the menu I am talling about
[image]

Is anyone aware on why is this happening? and how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: The module has a problem. If you go to Control Panel > Configuration > Gogo Shell and type 'lb' you will see a list of modules. Then type 'diag' followed by your module number and you should see a diagnosis of the problem.

Comment: Try creating a new mvc-portlet, making sure to select Liferay version 7.1 and deploy it to the server. This vanilla portlet should run without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this,

This was due to a missing step ( maybe missing from Liferay tutorial or I paid low attention ) , I had to run initBundle gradle task and then run the server. Make sure that the server was pointing to the bundles folder which get created automatically in Liferay workspace.

After that my portlet appeared.